# How to remove UICollectionView cells

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I need to add a button to my UICollectionView cells in order to let the user delete them, I tried with the following method on a button (just to test if I was able or not to delete a cell):

`[self.customCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:6 inSection:0]]];`

But I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 6 from section 0 which only contains 6 items before the update
```

If I change the indexPathForItem to <6 (for example 1) I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (6) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
```

Is there any way to implement deletion of cell from a UICollectionView or I'll keep gettin these errors?

Comment: You have to 'synchronize' your datasource as well... Are you removing the item from your datasource? Can you share some relevant code?

Comment: just with this comment you enlightened me :D got it working waaaay too easily, i'll post down what worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this pretty easily:
All the data that populates my cell were stored on a NSArray, I just needed to change it to an NSMutableArray and add on the delete button the following method

```
- (IBAction)DeleteCell:(id)sender {
    //delete item from NSMutableArray
    [_feedItems removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    // Now delete the items from the collection view.
    [self.customCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0]]];
}
```

Now I just need to pass the real IndexPath from the buttons i'll set onto the cells